# Can't get angular binding to work between template and directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get the user's current coordinates from my controller into my template, and from there into my directive. The first half of this works, but I can't get the second half working for the life of me. In the directive, I've also tried '=' and lat=currentLat, as well as scope/$scope. What's going on?

Controller:

```
var posOptions = { timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 5000 };
$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
    .then(function (location) {
        $scope.currentLat = location.coords.latitude;
        $scope.currentLong = location.coords.longitude;
        console.log($scope.currentLat, $scope.currentLong);
    });
```

Template:

```
<div id="map" zoom="16" bgeo lat="{{currentLat}}" lng="{{currentLong}}">
```

Directive:

```
.directive('bgeo', ['$cordovaGeolocation', '$cordovaBackgroundGeolocation', '$http', function ($cordovaGeolocation, $cordovaBackgroundGeolocation, $http) {
return {
    scope: {
       lat: '@',
       lng: '@'
   },
    link: function (scope) {
        console.log("directive: ", scope.lat, scope.lng);
    }
}}])
```

Full code of test app can be found here: https://github.com/sahiltalwar88/binding-geolocation-issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `@` in the template it is a one time string binding. Since you are waiting on the asynchronous `.getCurrentPosition` to complete the values are not updated until after they are already linked in the directive.  The linking function is only called when the directive is compiled.

Instead you will want to defer the directive's loading until the scope values are loaded. You can prevent compiling of the directive by leaving it out of the DOM via `ng-if`:

```
<div bgeo ng-if=loaded lat={{currentLat}} lng={{currentLng}}>
```

The directive won't be compiled or linked until `loaded` is set to true which you can do in the `.getCurrentPosition` callback:

http://plnkr.co/edit/eYWXCA5UE6dUu9RM5mdj?p=preview

You can also use *data binding* with `=` in the isolate scope definition. However, note that the directive is still only linked after it is initially compiled so the `console.log` will be called too early. It would make more sense to do this if you were using the bound values in a template or controller -- particularly if you will alter them and have that propogate back to the parent controller.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZXwDr3Tq3w046G7FM4mK?p=preview

Comment: I think I'd like to do the latter; I'm trying to keep a (google) map updated to the user's current location. However, the latter example uses 'template' instead of 'link' - could you explain how to do that using 'link' instead? I don't think I can simply create the template on the fly like that, since I'm dealing with the map. I could certainly be wrong, however.

Comment: @SahilTalwar `link` only runs *once* after the directive is compiled. You use `link` to do some initial setup sans data bindings.  There is no way to defer linking on its own -- you have to defer the compiling of the directive. It would help to know what your end goal is to really help you.

Comment: The end goal is simply to:
1. use geolocation to get a user's coordinates (which also is needed to prime background geolocation)
2. Create a map centered on those coordinates with the user's location indicated on the map
3. Use _background_ geolocation to keep the map updated to where the user is. 

Does that make sense?

Comment: Got it working after all! Thank you for your help, you put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working:

Template:

```
<ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" style="width:90%">
   <div ng-if="loaded" bgeo lat="currentLat" lng="currentLong">
       <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>
   </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('testApp.controllers', ['ionic', 'ngCordova.plugins.geolocation', 'ngCordova.plugins.backgroundGeolocation'])

.controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope', '$ionicPopup', '$cordovaGeolocation', '$cordovaBackgroundGeolocation', '$timeout', '$http', 
               function ($scope, $ionicPopup, $cordovaGeolocation, $cordovaBackgroundGeolocation, $timeout, $http) {
    $scope.loaded = false;

    var posOptions = { timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 5000 };
    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
        .then(function (location) {
            $scope.currentLat = location.coords.latitude;
            $scope.currentLong = location.coords.longitude;
            $scope.loaded = true;
        });
}])
```

Directive:

```
.directive('bgeo', ['$cordovaGeolocation', '$cordovaBackgroundGeolocation', '$http', 
           function ($cordovaGeolocation, $cordovaBackgroundGeolocation, $http) {
    return {
        scope: {
           lat: '=',
           lng: '='
       },
        link: function (scope) {
            console.log("directive: ", scope.lat, scope.lng);
                myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(scope.lat, scope.lng);
                mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 16,
                    center: myLatLng
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    draggable: false,
                    icon: 'small-orange-pin.png'
                });
        }
    }
}])
```